# submit button is not working on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a submit button inside a form like-

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $("#VEGAS").submit(function() {
        $('#One').click(function() {
          var form_data = $("#VEGAS").serialize();
          var routeUrl = "<?= url('/') ?>/vpage";
          $.ajax({
            url: routeUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data + '&jegy=' + test,
            success: function(result) {
              $('#alert').html('successfully added!');
              $('#msg-group').delay(1000).hide('slow');
            }
          });
        });
        return false;
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="One" type="submit" name="submit_5" class="submitBTN addnowBtn" value="Light Nightclub">Add Now</button>
```

Every thing is working fine but above button is not working on first click. How can i get rid of this issue ?

Comment: Where do you call that button click, I cant find anything that match your html and jquery together. You also seem to have a `click` event inside a `submit` event

Comment: This function should never be called as per to your code

Comment: I have edited the code the button id was incorrect

Comment: click function is not required inside submit function, submit function is enough to submit the form

Comment: I have defined specific login in my controller on the basis of button click. Because i have multiple button on my form

Comment: 2 ways to remedy this is you register `#on` to the submit event  or wrap `#on` in a `<form>` element. Don't know if `#vegas` is a form? You need to post HTML

Comment: You kept click function inside Submit function that's why you needed twice click. Button type is submit that's why first click triggering submit and creating scope for button click when you clicking second time then it triggering. You should keep click function outside of submit function in this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#One').click(function(){...})
```

should be registered in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {...})
```

as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#One').click(function(){...})
});
```

since, in your code you are registering the `$('#One').click()` in `$("#VEGAS").submit()` therefore the `$('#One').click()` is registered when the `$("#VEGAS").submit()` gets called for the first time. Hence, in the first attemp this doesn't works but works in the second attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: you are binding click event handler for one button inside form submit hence it is binding click event handler on first click and on second click it is calling click handler.
You can remove click event for button and use below jquery code
HTML:

```
<button id="One" type="submt" name="submit_5" class="submitBTN addnowBtn" value="Light Nightclub">Add Now</button>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                $('#VEGAS').on("click",function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var form_data = $("#VEGAS").serialize();
                    var routeUrl = "<?= url('/') ?>/vpage";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: routeUrl,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: form_data + '&jegy=' + test,
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#alert').html('successfully added!');
                            $('#msg-group').delay(1000).hide('slow');
                         }
                    });
            });
```

Comment: I would say `onsubmit` makes more sense here than `click`

Comment: Although i have multiple button on my form ?

Comment: multiple button with same id? or multiple button to submit same form?

Comment: multiple button with different id on same form

Comment: in this case you should use summit form event handler only and remove button click handler which is not required. see my updated post

Answer (score 2):

Inside `submit()` the `.click()` is unnecessary:-

Remove `$('#One').click(function () {`

Use either one (either `.submit()`  or `.click()`)

So:-

Either

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#VEGAS").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form_data = $("#VEGAS").serialize();
            var routeUrl = "<?= url('/') ?>/vpage";
            $.ajax({
                url: routeUrl,
                type: "POST",
                data: form_data + '&jegy=' + test,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#alert').html('successfully added!');
                    $('#msg-group').delay(1000).hide('slow');
                 }
            });
        return false;
    }); 
});//missed in your code
</script>
```

Or

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#One').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $("#VEGAS").serialize();
        var routeUrl = "<?= url('/') ?>/vpage";
        $.ajax({
            url: routeUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data + '&jegy=' + test,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#alert').html('successfully added!');
                $('#msg-group').delay(1000).hide('slow');
             }
        });
    });
    return false;
}); //missed in your code
</script>
```

Note:-

if you have multiple id which are same then it's completely wrong. either covert them to class or give different id to each-one

***Check your browser developer console to see all errors which are raised and rectify all of those***

Comment: dear i have different button in #Vegas form with different ids.

Comment: @Learner  change the above code accordingly. (put your desired id there or use form submit)

Answer (score 1):

```
  var routeUrl = "<?= url('/') ?>/vpage";
```

Here is the error. use static path here.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $("#VEGAS").submit(function () {

                    var form_data = $("#VEGAS").serialize();
                    var routeUrl = "vpage";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: routeUrl,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: form_data + '&jegy=' + test,
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#alert').html('successfully added!');
                            $('#msg-group').delay(1000).hide('slow');
                         }
                    });

                return false;
            }); 
 }); 
</script>
```